# SQL Union query - Multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables (Projects and Documents), both have an ID and Name field.

I'm looking for a query that meets the following requirments:
- it will return rows from either table that have specfied words in the 'Name' field
- it will return 3 fields: ID, Name and TableName -- where the tablename will be either be the name of the table or some identifier

I tried:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM projects UNION SELECT id, name FROM documents
WHERE name like '%querystriong%'
```

But this query does not add the 3rd (TableName) field and it returns rows from the Projects table that that have associated documents with querystring in the name field.

I'm suspecting I'm tackling this completely wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
SELECT id, name, 'projects' AS table_name 
FROM projects WHERE name like '%querystriong%' UNION SELECT id, name, 'documents' AS table_name
FROM documents WHERE name like '%querystriong%'
```

Comment: Brilliant and so simple!  Thank you.  I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Think of each select in a union as a discreet query whose result set columns must match. This means that each query must have a WHERE clause as well if you want to filter it. Additionally, you can add a literal to each query to say where it came from.

This means your query should be something like:

```
SELECT id, name 'projects' AS TableName FROM projects  WHERE name like '%querystring%'
UNION
SELECT id, name, 'documents' AS TableName FROM documents WHERE name like '%querystring%'
```

Alternatively, you can express it as:

```
SELECT id, name, tablename FROM (
  SELECT id, name, 'projects' as tablename
  UNION
  SELECT id, name, 'documents' as tablename
) AS combinedtable WHERE name like '%querystring%'
```

The second option may give you more control over your WHERE clause since you don't need to duplicate it then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly but this query may help:

```
    SELECT id, name, 'projects' as tablename
    FROM   projects
    WHERE  name like '%querysting%'
    UNION
    SELECT id, name, 'documents'
    FROM   documents
    WHERE  name like '%querystring%'
```